# How to use Unicode character literal for Han characters in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to create a Unicode character for U+20BB7, but I can't seem to figure out a way.

```
\uD842\uDFB7
```

The above doesn't work. I'm starting to think that you can't use literal Unicode character syntax for characters above `\uFFFF`.

Are my only option to use a string instead?

```
"\uD842\uDFB7"
```

Since as a string it works?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23902953/using-emoji-literals-in-clojure-source

Comment: While this is a somewhat duplicate question, the accepted answer I was given here is more accurate in my opinion to the answers in the other question. I'd suggest interested readers to read the answer here first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use a string here - you're basically trying to shove two 'char' (16bit) values into one. See [1]

> Unicode Character Representations
>
> The char data type (and therefore the value that a Character object
>   encapsulates) are based on the original Unicode specification, which
>   defined characters as fixed-width 16-bit entities. The Unicode
>   Standard has since been changed to allow for characters whose
>   representation requires more than 16 bits. The range of legal code
>   points is now U+0000 to U+10FFFF, known as Unicode scalar value.
>   (Refer to the definition of the U+n notation in the Unicode Standard.)

1: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html